# plone: How to re-register a view after enabling/disabling marker behavior

Tags: plone, dexterity

I created a view that should be available if a behavior is enabled.

```
from behaviors import IMyBehavior

class View(grok.View):
    grok.context(IMyBehavior)
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.name('my-view')
```

I also added the behavior to the configure.zcml

```
  <include package="plone.behavior" file="meta.zcml" />

  <plone:behavior
        title="My View Behavior"
        description="foobar"
        provides=".behaviors.IMyBehavior"
        />
```

After read the section **Primary marker behaviors** at http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/behaviors/referencemanual-all-pages I though this would be enough. But apparently it isn't.
When I enable MyBehavior TTW and then try to open my-view the view is not available.

I realized that if I restart my plone instance after enabling/disabling the behavior it works as expected. I guess after enabling a behavior TTW the view must be re-registered.

The question now is how can I do that?

Comment: Can you check whether IMyBehavior is provided by instances of your content, e.g. install Products.PdbDebugMode, invoke the /@@pdb view on one of your instances (or use plone.app.debugtoolbar) and then check e.g. IMyBehavior.providedBy(context)

Comment: @optilude: I installed plone.app.debugtoolbar and indeed IMyBehavior.providedBy(context) is False until I restart the server instance. I also tried this with plone.app.versioningbehavior.behaviors.IVersioningSupport. IVersioningSupport.providedBy(context) is also false until I restart, but the functionality of IVersioningSupport seems to work OK without a restart.

Comment: I opened a ticket https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13160

Answer (score 2):

Views cannot be re-registered.

The registration is written to Zope component registry upon the momemt Zope application server starts and Python modules are imported. This is one time operation and related to your code, not your data.

More like the issue sounds that something else falls apart in the process. Maybe content type does not in fact provide the behavior marker interface in the question. This could be because of something is interfering the process: your code is not read on start-up or there is an internal bug in plone.behaviors. Please see optilude's comment how to test whether the marker interface is available or not.